# Image Uploading Laravel 5.2 : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload an images using method moving the temporary files, and show it on my index page only with the path.

Here's the problem:

```
ErrorException in ProductController.php line 69: Trying to get property of non-object
```

In my controller that contain the line who error:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product=Request::all();
    Product::create($product);


    $imageName = $product->id_prod . '.' . 
        $request->file('images')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->file('images')->move(
        base_path() . '/public/images/catalog/', $imageName
    );  

    return redirect('product');
}
```

And here's the database, the file has been uploaded on temp folder, but the file was fail to moved. I'm using Laravel 5.2, it was my first time to upload a files. And can someone explain to me why this one could be error.

Sorry for my bad grammars.

[image: Images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = $request->all();

    $picture = '';

    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
        $file = $request->file('images');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $picture = $product['id_prod'] . '.' . $extension;
        $destinationPath = base_path() . '/public/images/catalog/';
        $request->file('images')->move($destinationPath, $picture);
    }

    if (!empty($product['images'])) {
        $product['images'] = $picture;
    } else {
        unset($product['images']);
    }


    Product::create($product);

    return redirect('/product');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it's suppose to be work, but another error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()`

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` Did you see something like this in your controller ?

Comment: I've added that but `Cannot use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request because the name is already in use`

Comment: I have remove `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` and change it to `Illuminate\Http\Request` so it will works, also id_prod isn't defined so I change it. Thank you!

Comment: I think `id_prod` is auto incremented column.

Comment: Yes it is. Can I use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` and `Illuminate\Http\Request` together? Because I needed both.